# Regex replace tags in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace, tags

I'm making a small parser in C#.

My string to parse is:

```
Hello [Name] [LastName] how are you? [FirstTime]this is your first time isnt it?[/FirstTime] Bye!
```

My C# code for the [Name] and [LastName] is:

```
  message = message
    .Replace("[FirstName]", user.FirstName)
    .Replace("[LastName]", user.LastName)
bool isFirstTime = user.FirstLogin;
```

My problem is between  `[FirstTime] [/FirstTime]`. If `isFirstTime` is true I want to keep the string between the tags and if it's false I want to throw away the text inside the tags.

Any idea how I could go for this problem?

Example result:

> Hello James Bond how are you? this is your first time isnt it? Bye!

**EDIT**: I forgot to say that the example string is just well an example and the string is "user defined" so using a stringbuilder isn't gonna work in my case.

Comment: Why regex? The first part could be done with `String.Format` and the second by appending to the string if the flag is `true`.

Comment: Yes but there is text after [FirstTime] [/FirstTime] as well

Comment: You could append that as well...

Comment: Yes that would work if the string wasn't dynamic :)

Comment: You can most certainly work with the Stringbuilder class, even with dynamic strings. It just depends on the order you want to display the sentences. It has nothing to do whether the content is 'a' or 'b'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex-way you might be looking for:

```
var FirstLogin = false;
var FirstName = "James";
var LastName = "Bond";
var message = "Hello [FirstName] [LastName] how are you? [FirstTime]this is your first time isnt it?[/FirstTime] Bye!";
message = message
         .Replace("[FirstName]", FirstName)
         .Replace("[LastName]", LastName);
var isFirstTime = FirstLogin;
if (FirstLogin)
    message = Regex.Replace(message, @"\[/?FirstTime\]", string.Empty);
    // Hello James Bond how are you? this is your first time isnt it? Bye!
else
    message = Regex.Replace(message, @"\[FirstTime\].*?\[/FirstTime\]", string.Empty);
    // Hello James Bond how are you?  Bye!
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

1. `\[/?FirstTime\]` - Matches `[FirstTime]` or `[/FirstTime]` literally
2. `\[FirstTime\].*?\[/FirstTime\]` - Matches any text between the closest occurrences of `[FirstTime]` and `[/FirstTime]` (not accounting for nested BBtags).

If you have nested tags, you might consider 2 regexes:

```
\[FirstTime\](?:(?!\[/?FirstTime\]).)*\[/FirstTime\]
```

This one above will match the closest pair of `FirstTime` tag. And the one below can match those farthest:

```
\[FirstTime\](?:\[([^]]*)\].*?\[/\1\]|.*?)*\[/FirstTime\]
```

Comment: Workd perfectly except this one works slightly better with nested:

Regex.Replace(message, @"s*\[FirstTime\](?=((?:[^\[]+|\[(?!\/?FirstTime\]))*))\1\[\/FirstTime\]\s", string.Empty);

Comment: @Caresi: I think the comment ate up some characters. I updated the answer with more options. Glad my answer worked out for you. Please consider also upvoting the answer if it proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

use this regex pattern to find and replace FirstName block:

```
[[FirstTime]](.*)[[/FirstTime]]
```

then your code may be :

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[[FirstTime]](.*)[[/FirstTime]]");
File.WriteAllText("", rgx.Replace("Hello [Name] [LastName] how are you? [FirstTime]this is your first time isnt it?[/FirstTime] Bye!", "Ali"));
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `.*` be non-greedy? I.e. `.*?`.

Comment: I wonder who upvoted it, the result is not the one expected: [`Hello [NamAli Bye!`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5bFirstTime%5d%5d(.*)%5b%5b%2fFirstTime%5d%5d&i=Hello+%5bName%5d+%5bLastName%5d+how+are+you%3f+%5bFirstTime%5dthis+is+your+first+time+isnt+it%3f%5b%2fFirstTime%5d+Bye!&r=Ali). The `[[FirstTime]](.*)[[/FirstTime]]` regex is definitely wrong, and it is not only the greediness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stringbuilder class:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("Hello ");

//Name
builder.Append(Name);
builder.Append(" ");
builder.Append(LastName);
builder.Append(" How are you? ");

//First time
if(FirstTime){
    builder.Append(" This is your first time isn't it? ");
}

//Bye
builder.Append(" Bye!");

//Convert to string
String sentence = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the string that im parsing is user defined, or rather dynamic so this wouldnt work then :/

Comment: Maybe it does not work this way exactly, but you can make it work easily with the Stringbuilder class with a bit of logic! Just replace the hard string values by variables / strings.